# Data from different tables using ajax and datepicker

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hello friends I am fetching data from database using ajax.

The problem is,I am using date picker of html on selection of date I get the bill id as button,now the problem is this whole thing is done using ajax. On button click I want to get order details but on the same page,how do I do this.

Here is the code.

oldbills.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get(str)
{
    //document.write("hi");
var xmlhttp;
if (str==0)
  { 
 alert("please select Table no");
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //  var dat=xmlhttp.responseText;
    //document.write(dat[0]);
    document.getElementById("showresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","fetchbills.php?dt="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="date" name="datepicker" id="picker" onchange="get(this.value)"/>
<div id="showresult">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

getting data from fetchbills.php
fetchbills.php

```
<?php
include("./config.php");
$dt = $_REQUEST["dt"];
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
function get(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str==0)
  { 
 alert('please select Table no');
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //  var dat=xmlhttp.responseText;
    //document.write(dat[0]);
    document.getElementById('showresult').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open('POST','fetchbilldetail.php',true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>";
//echo $dt;
$sql="select bill_id,order_id from bill_master where order_date='$dt'";
//echo $sql;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("error");
//echo "<table><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
if($result)
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //echo "1";
echo $row[0]."<br>";    
echo "<form method='post' action=''><input type='submit' name='det' value='".$row[1]."' onclick='get(this.value)' /></form>
<div id='showresult'></div>";
//  echo "<tr><td>".$row[4]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>";
}
}
//echo "</table>";
?>
```

I thought I can use ajax in this page also and fetch data from 3 page and display it on 1 page.

but the link is redirected and data is displayed on 3 page.

fetchbilldetail.php

```
<?php
include("./config.php");
$det = $_POST["det"];
//echo $det;
$sql="SELECT m.old_order_id,m.old_order_amount,l.item_id,l.old_order_quantity,i.item_name from old_order_master m,old_order_list l,item_list i where m.old_order_id=$det and m.old_order_id=l.old_order_id and l.item_id=i.item_id";
//echo $sql;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<table><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr><td>".$row[4]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

How do I get the data on single page.

Comment: can't you use Jquery ajax in that ??

Comment: I don't know how to do,can you provide some example

Comment: yes vinita.  instead of using XMLHttpRequest there is better and easy way to fetch server side data using ajax(jquery) is [link]https://www.sitepoint.com/demos/ajax/

Comment: thank you,will try to implement it. @TejasMehta

Comment: :) best Luck @vinita

Comment: tried ajax but still have doubts..@TejasMehta

Comment: what kinda doughts you have ?? @vinita

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the ajax demo.But I want to know how I get another data.

here is the code I am getting data from a php page.

oldbills.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
         <input type="date" name="gdate" id="gdate" onchange="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"/>
      </form>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 function makeAjaxRequest(dateval){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data: { dateva: dateval }, 
          url: "fetchbills.php",
          success: function(data) {
           $('#showresult').html(data);
          }
        });
      }

 $("#gdate").on("change", function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
          makeAjaxRequest(id);

      });
 </script>
<div id="showresult">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

fetchbills.php

```
<?php
include("./config.php");
$dt = $_REQUEST["dateva"];
//echo $dt;
$sql="select bill_id,order_id from bill_master where order_date='$dt'";
echo $sql;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("error");
//echo "<table><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
if($result)
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //echo "1";
echo $row[0]."<br>";    
echo "<form method='post' action=''><input type='submit' name='det' value='".$row[1]."' onclick='get(this.value)' /></form>";
//  echo "<tr><td>".$row[4]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>";
}
}
//echo "</table>";
?>
```

[image]

these are the buttons which is the data fetched from php,now on click of these buttons I want to fetch data from the table.how do I do it.

Comment: you are going right way.. just check my answer for the further process

Answer (score 0):

that's fine... you are getting button as the output now don't write button onclick attribute there

in the **fetchbills.php** just this :

```
echo "<form method='post' action=''><input type='submit' name='det' value='".$row[1]." id='det'/></form>";
```

now in the js file write the code as

```
$(document).on('click','#det',function(){
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data: { //your button id to be pass in the data  }, 
          url: "yourUrl.php",
          success: function(data) {
             $('resultID').html(data);
          }
        });
});
```

and in the yourUrl.php
write the code to fetch the bill details based on ID you send.
so by this you will your result as you want..
its ajax call 2 times . first   for the fetch button and another for the fetch bill..
**Enjoy**